# How to set application icon in JavaFX 15-ea+3

Tags: java, gradle, javafx, jpackage

I have made a JavaFX project with the following details:

**`OpenJFX 15-ea+3` / `JDK 14` / `Gradle` / `Non-modular`**

Also, I use the following Gradle plugins:

**`javafxplugin version 0.0.8` / `org.beryx.runtime version 1.8.2` & `com.github.johnrengelman.shadow version 5.2.0` (For creating native images)**

In addition, JDK 14 `jpackage` tool is used to create installer package for the application. Here is `build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.8'
    id 'org.beryx.runtime' version '1.8.2'
    id "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow" version "5.2.0"
}

group 'com.pastor'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 14
targetCompatibility = 14
//This option is for rendering persian characters encoding
compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'

javafx {
    version = "15-ea+3"
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml']
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    runtimeOnly "org.openjfx:javafx-controls:$javafx.version:win"
    runtimeOnly "org.openjfx:javafx-fxml:$javafx.version:win"
    runtimeOnly "org.openjfx:javafx-media:$javafx.version:win"
    compile group: 'com.jfoenix', name: 'jfoenix', version: '9.0.9'
    compile 'de.jensd:fontawesomefx-fontawesome:4.7.0-9.1.2'
    compile 'de.jensd:fontawesomefx-icons525:4.2.0-9.1.2'
    compile 'de.jensd:fontawesomefx-materialdesignfont:2.0.26-9.1.2'
    compile 'de.jensd:fontawesomefx-materialicons:2.2.0-9.1.2'
    compile group: 'org.controlsfx', name: 'controlsfx', version: '11.0.1'
}

runtime {
    options = ['--strip-debug', '--compress', '2', '--no-header-files', '--no-man-pages']
    jpackage {
        if(org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem.current().windows) {
            appVersion = '1.0.0'
            skipInstaller = false
            installerName = 'Pastor apartment unit management system'
            installerType = 'exe'
            installerOptions = ['--win-per-user-install', '--win-dir-chooser', '--win-menu', '--win-shortcut']
        }
    }
}
mainClassName = 'sample.Launcher'
```

I already tried `imageOptions = ['--icon icon.ico']` within `jpackage` block but I always get this kind of error:

```
Error: Invalid Option: [--icon app.ico]
```

Any useful suggestions or tips are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used that plugin but I would try adding `'--icon', 'icon.ico'` to the installerOptions and not the imageOptions.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not too late, or for anyone else with this issue,instead of

```
imageOptions = ['--icon icon.ico']
```

use

```
imageOptions = ['--icon', 'icon.ico']
```

This worked for me.